# Alternative if javascript is disabled in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

Is there any alternative way to call javascript when javascript is disabled in your browser?

Means if i am using ajax and also jquery validation which are must for the further process but my javascript is disabled in browser. So what should i do ? How to validate and get the values of the ajax call ?

Comment: You should always always validate server side. Always. Enabling all forms for non-JS users shouldn't really be necessary. Who turns off their JS!?

Comment: @Rudie lots of corporate machines have JS disabled by jobsworth IT managers who fear viruses.

Comment: you validate from server as well as from client you make your ajax as a normal page first then your js & ajax with a return false to prevent the http request meant for non js user - not for the lazy obviously & the only proper practice anyway

Comment: we also have same situation.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan What do JS and virusses have to do with each other? That's some crappy IT managers. That's some crappy internet experience for those users.

Comment: @Rudie check the top answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/302963/how-can-i-get-a-virus-by-just-visiting-a-website

Comment: You can get viruses from everything in a computer... It's still not really related to JS. Updating IE to a modern version would help more. Anyways. No JS = no JS. Viruses =) So funny.

Answer (score 4):

No, if javascript is disabled, then you can't enable it or use it without the help of the user.

But you should consider that it's a very rare occurrence and that users deciding to disable javascript support the choice of their decision, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: To add to what @dystroy says, you can use the `<noscript>` tags to display a friendly warning to the user that your site requires javascript and it will not work without it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any alternative way to call javascript when javascript is disabled in your browser?

No. Disabled is disabled.

> Means if i am using ajax and also jquery validation which are must for the further process but my javascript is disabled in browser. So what should i do ? How to validate and get the values of the ajax call ?

Perform the validation server side.

Present the results of the data processing by generating a new HTML document on the server.

Follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

If javascript is disabled you cannot do any javascript controller (of course).

However some HTML5 attribute can force the browser to do some basic control. Such `type="email"` or `type="url"`.

These validation, in some recent browser, are available with js disabled too.